# Limiting Firebase in-memory caching

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm aggregating a large amount of data into Firebase on an EC2 Micro instance using node.js. The app scans a number of sources for photos and maintains a Firebase of meta-data about each photo such as URL, size, origin, "likes" etc.

I also keep a few aggregate indexes updated (by date, by likes etc.). The actual code is pretty straightforward:

```
var db = new Firebase('https://my.firebaseio.com')

// Whenever the aggregator updates a photo, update the popularity inedx
db.child('photos').on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    var instagram = snapshot.child('likes/instagram').val() || 0,
        facebook = snapshot.child('likes/facebook').val() || 0,
        likes = instagram + facebook

    // Update popularity index
    db.child('index/popularity').child(snapshot.name()).setWithPriority(true, likes)
})
```

Since my instance (t1.micro) only has 615mb of RAM available I'm running out of RAM as Firebase caches all the children of the `photos` collection while they are being updated.

Is there a way to prevent Firebase from exhausting all available RAM with its in-memory cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase keeps a cache of everything that you currently have outstanding callbacks on. So as soon as you do an on() at a location, we'll load all of the data and keep it in memory. We have to do this so that we can calculate diffs and simulate local events.

Are you storing the actual images in Firebase?

If you have a large amount of data and you don't want it all to get loaded, I suggest separating out the big chunks of data and only syncing the metadata. For example you could store your photos at /photos but store info about likes and other metadata at /photos_metadata.

If you're just working with metadata and you have a ton of it, what you should do is maintain a queue of "recent changes". Then when a client updates some piece of data, it will also push to the queue. Your node process then just listens to that queue, processes the change, and deletes the queue entry. If it needs to sync the metadata during processing it can do so on a photo-by-photo basis and then call off() when it's done (or just use once()).